# javascript convert set to comma separated string - IE11

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I'm having issues to convert a `Set` to a `comma separated string` in IE11, the below works fine in chrome, but IE11 doesn't like `Array.from`.

```
let a = new Set();
a.add("a");
a.add("b");

console.log(Array.from(a).join(","));
```

To get a work around I'm doing:

```
let aArray = [];                        
let pushToArray = function(val) {
  aArray.push(val);
};
a.forEach(pushToArray);

console.log(aArray.toString());
```

Any suggestion on how to do the above better that works in IE11?

Comment: Looks like you found a valid workaround already. What about it doesn't work for you? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility for info on what functions of your Set you can use if you have to support IE11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be better, if you don't even build an array from it, only create the string using concatenation:

```js
let a = new Set();
a.add("a");
a.add("b");

function SetToString(set, delim){
  let str = '';
  set.forEach(function(elem){
    str += elem + delim
  });
  return str
}
console.log(SetToString(a, ','));
```

The only issue with this approach is that it will add a comma at the end as well.

To avoid this, you have two ways:

- Remove the last comma using `.slice(0, -1)`

  ```
  let a = new Set();
  a.add("a");
  a.add("b");

  function SetToString(set, delim){
    let str = '';
    set.forEach(function(elem){
      str += elem + delim
    });
    return str.slice(0, -1)
  }
  console.log(SetToString(a, ','));
  ```
- Count elements, and omit comma for the last

  ```
  let a = new Set();
  a.add("a");
  a.add("b");

  function SetToString(set, delim){
    let str = '';
    let i = 0;
    let size = set.size;
    set.forEach(function(elem){
      str += elem
      if(i++ < size - 1) str += delim
    });
    return str
  }
  console.log(SetToString(a, ','));
  ```

Comment: blegh. javascript is awful

Comment: @KellenStuart Well, that's how you'd do that in most of the programming languages.

Comment: In C#: `var arr = myHashSet.toArray()`. JS has the worst standard library I've ever seen.

Comment: @KellenStuart while I agree with the general premise that there is room for improvement in JS I'd like to also point out that it is an evolving language and it's limitation in this case are due to browser support. As OP pointed out, there is an easy way for this in javascript too: `Array.from(mySet).join(", ")`, which is about as 'awful' as it would be in C# (`string.Join(", ", mySet.toArray())` I believe, been a while).

Answer (score 1):

This question is the first hit on google now when searching for `javascript join set with comma` (and likely other, similar queries).

If you're here because **you want to do this** and don't care about IE11 anymore, read the question again carefully. The easy way is:

```
const commaSeparatedString = Array.from(new Set(['a', 'b', 'a'])).join(", ")
console.log(commaSeparatedString)

// => "a, b"
```

Note: This is not the correct answer to the initial question, just a headsup for those seeking an answer to what google thinks they are looking for.
The answer from @FZs should still be the accepted answer!